# ¿Se usa "ses" o "se" al referirse a más de una persona?

Tags: pronombres

¿Cómo se dice al recomendar algo a alguien?

> **Ses** lo recomiendo

o

> **Se** los recomiendo

Siempre he tenido esa duda.

Comment: _Ses_ no es un pronombre que exista en español. Ses es Extremo final del intestino.  http://dle.rae.es/?id=XiANrev

Comment: @Erica Mireles, tengo una curiosidad: ¿es el español tu lengua nativa?

Answer (score 2):

En respuesta a ambos, es correcto lo que dice Maurocrispin en cuanto a que "se" funciona como objeto indirecto tanto singular como plural:

- Se lo recomiendo (a él, a usted, a ellos, a ustedes).

Existe una tendencia INCORRECTA a pluralizar el objeto directo pronominal LO o LA para indicar pluralidad en el objeto indirecto. La tendencia sin duda proviene de la necesidad del hablante de remarcar que se está dirigiendo a más de una persona. No obstante, el uso de "los" o "las" es incorrecto cuando el objeto directo (lo recomendado, en este caso) es singular y la persona que recibe la recomendación, plural.

Si queremos dejar en claro que nos dirigimos a más de una persona, no habrá otra opción que duplicar el objeto indirecto:

- Se lo recomiendo a ustedes. (ej. un libro)
- Se la recomiendo a ellas. (ej. una revista)

Answer (score 1):

"Se lo recomiendo" si tú recomiendas algo al alguien, por ejemplo tú recomiendas un servicio a alguien.

"Se los recomiendo" si tu recomiendas algo(plural) a alguien, por ejemplo tú recomiendas los productos de x marca a alguien.

"Lo" sustituye al servicio.

Mientras que "Los" sustituye a "Los productos"

Me has puesto a pensar, porque sí yo recomendara un solo objeto a varias personas, por ejemplo un restaurante a dos amigos, diría;

"Se los recomiendo"

Aunque no estoy seguro sí es correcto, ojalá que alguien pueda aportar más.

Comment: **Se**, sustituye a los pronombres **le** y **les**.

Comment: Es verdad, pero para poder utilizar "le" o "les" deberá explicitarse el objeto directo: Le recomiendo un libro (a él, a usted) - Les recomiendo una revista (a ellos, a ustedes)